# React: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') - render JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await

I have seen a few posts with a similar error but am struggling with it here because I'm not super familiar with generic types and try as I might I just can't fully figure out async and promises.  In any event, this Typescript code can't find an initial value for article.  I really don't want a default value, but I've tried null, I've tried putting in a array with a single dummy object, and every combination I can think of.  Can anyone help me get a list of articles from the database and just map them as list items?

Here's the type.

```
export type article = {
  article_id: number
  organization_id: number
  title: string
  subtitle: string
  article_text: string
  publish_date: Date | null
  end_date: Date | null
  created_date: Date
  modified_date: Date
  created_by: string
  modified_by: string
}
```

And the code

````
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import React from "react";

export default async function TestCrap() {
    const [articles, setArticles] =
        useState<article[]>([
        {
            article_id: 1,
            organization_id: 1,
            title: "string",
            subtitle: "string",
            article_text: "string",
            publish_date: null,
            end_date: null,
            created_date: new Date("2022-01-01"),
            modified_date: new Date("2022-01-01"),
            created_by: "string",
            modified_by: "string",
        },
    ]);

    const prisma = new PrismaClient();

    useEffect(() => {
        prisma.article.findMany().then((a) => setArticles(a));
    }, []);

    // const count: number = await prisma.person.count();
    // const count: number = 999;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>TEST CRAP</h1>
            {/* <h3>Count: {count.toString()}</h3> */}
            <ul>
                {articles.length > 0 &&
                    articles.map((value, index) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <li key={index}>Title: {value.title}</li>
                            </>
                        );
                    })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}```
````

Comment: the problem is with the state articles ? giving an empty array does not work I believe ?
And I don't understand the use of `async` for your component

Comment: You are returning a Promises, not a React Component, maybe the problem is this

Answer (score 0):

You should use `null` as default value:

```
export default function TestCrap() {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState<article[] | null>(null);

  const prisma = new PrismaClient();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const articles = await prisma.article.findMany();
      setArticles(articles);
    })()
  }, []);

  if (articles == null) {
    // if articles is still null we can't return the list
    return <>Fetching the articles...</>;
  }

  // here we have the articles typed
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>TEST CRAP</h1>
      <ul>
        {articles.length > 0 &&
          articles.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>Title: {value.title}</li>
            );
         })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this way, you don't need a dumb array as initial value.

Also, delete the keyword `async` from the function definition.